# Parse XML data and compare values

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an XML structure as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<answer>
    <flows>
        <flow>
            <reference type="from">
                <statement>
                    <statementfull>virtualinvoke $r0.&lt;de.foellix.sourceapp.SourceMainActivity: void startActivity(android.content.Intent)&gt;($r1)</statementfull>
                    <statementgeneric>de.foellix.sourceapp.SourceMainActivity: void startActivity(android.content.Intent)</statementgeneric>
                    <parameters>
                        <parameter>
                            <type>android.content.Intent</type>
                            <value>$r1</value>
                        </parameter>
                    </parameters>
                </statement>
                <method>&lt;de.foellix.sourceapp.SourceMainActivity: void source()&gt;</method>
                <classname>de.foellix.sourceapp.SourceMainActivity</classname>
                <app>
                    <file>C:/SIMApp.apk</file>
                    <hashes>
                        <hash type="MD5">e98d0f782a61c81ee8da971ebff5cec9</hash>
                        <hash type="SHA-1">e1516eff8cc99f9dfb49bea3a7ec8588e0c7a4ab</hash>
                        <hash type="SHA-256">492df0663a4ca21f22c7d9bb613b43d914a78352a4f77e548846f39b6e823c3</hash>
                    </hashes>
                </app>
            </reference>
            <reference type="to">
                <statement>
                    <statementfull>$r2 = virtualinvoke $r1.&lt;android.content.Intent: java.lang.String getStringExtra(java.lang.String)&gt;("Secret")</statementfull>
                    <statementgeneric>android.content.Intent: java.lang.String getStringExtra(java.lang.String)</statementgeneric>
                    <parameters>
                        <parameter>
                            <type>java.lang.String</type>
                            <value>"Secret"</value>
                        </parameter>
                    </parameters>
                </statement>
                <method>&lt;de.foellix.sinkapp.SinkMainActivity: void sink()&gt;</method>
                <classname>de.foellix.sinkapp.SinkMainActivity</classname>
                <app>
                    <file>C:/SMSApp.apk</file>
                    <hashes>
                        <hash type="MD5">505197d8859303afc60ffee8ff298f39</hash>
                        <hash type="SHA-1">9c2ef3ad3b0376f6c023bfca15f402f0eb00c976</hash>
                        <hash type="SHA-256">8a90c056a029f2d032705be20216e8888b735131304a128752e516ac21d87a03</hash>
                    </hashes>
                </app>
            </reference>
        </flow>
        <flow>
            <reference type="from">
                <statement>
                    <statementfull>virtualinvoke $r0.&lt;de.foellix.sourceapp.SourceMainActivity: void startActivity(android.content.Intent)&gt;($r1)</statementfull>
                    <statementgeneric>de.foellix.sourceapp.SourceMainActivity: void startActivity(android.content.Intent)</statementgeneric>
                    <parameters>
                        <parameter>
                            <type>android.content.Intent</type>
                            <value>$r1</value>
                        </parameter>
                    </parameters>
                </statement>
                <method>&lt;de.foellix.sourceapp.SourceMainActivity: void source()&gt;</method>
                <classname>de.foellix.sourceapp.SourceMainActivity</classname>
                <app>
                    <file>C:/SIMApp.apk</file>
                    <hashes>
                        <hash type="MD5">e98d0f782a61c81ee8da971ebff5cec9</hash>
                        <hash type="SHA-1">e1516eff8cc99f9dfb49bea3a7ec8588e0c7a4ab</hash>
                        <hash type="SHA-256">492df0663a4ca21f22c7d9bb613b43d914a78352a4f77e548846f39b6e823c3</hash>
                    </hashes>
                </app>
            </reference>
            <reference type="to">
                <statement>
                    <statementfull>virtualinvoke $r0.&lt;de.foellix.sourceapp.SourceMainActivity: void startActivity(android.content.Intent)&gt;($r1)</statementfull>
                    <statementgeneric>de.foellix.sourceapp.SourceMainActivity: void startActivity(android.content.Intent)</statementgeneric>
                    <parameters>
                        <parameter>
                            <type>android.content.Intent</type>
                            <value>$r1</value>
                        </parameter>
                    </parameters>
                </statement>
                <method>&lt;de.foellix.sourceapp.SourceMainActivity: void source()&gt;</method>
                <classname>de.foellix.sourceapp.SourceMainActivity</classname>
                <app>
                    <file>C:/SIMApp.apk</file>
                    <hashes>
                        <hash type="MD5">e98d0f782a61c81ee8da971ebff5cec9</hash>
                        <hash type="SHA-1">e1516eff8cc99f9dfb49bea3a7ec8588e0c7a4ab</hash>
                        <hash type="SHA-256">492df0663a4ca21f22c7d9bb613b43d914a78352a4f77e548846f39b6e823c3</hash>
                    </hashes>
                </app>
            </reference>
        </flow>
      ...
    </flows>
</answer>
```

I am looking to parse this XML data where there are multiple `<flow>` elements within the  element.

For each `<flow>` element I want to compare the `<hash type="SHA-256">` values inside the `<reference type="from">` and `<reference type="to">` and get only the `<flow>` elements in which the `<hash type="SHA-256">` values are different.

For example for the above XML the output should look something like this

```
<flow>
    <reference type="from">
        <statement>
            <statementfull>virtualinvoke $r0.&lt;de.foellix.sourceapp.SourceMainActivity: void startActivity(android.content.Intent)&gt;($r1)</statementfull>
            <statementgeneric>de.foellix.sourceapp.SourceMainActivity: void startActivity(android.content.Intent)</statementgeneric>
            <parameters>
                <parameter>
                    <type>android.content.Intent</type>
                    <value>$r1</value>
                </parameter>
            </parameters>
        </statement>
        <method>&lt;de.foellix.sourceapp.SourceMainActivity: void source()&gt;</method>
        <classname>de.foellix.sourceapp.SourceMainActivity</classname>
        <app>
            <file>C:/SIMApp.apk</file>
            <hashes>
                <hash type="MD5">e98d0f782a61c81ee8da971ebff5cec9</hash>
                <hash type="SHA-1">e1516eff8cc99f9dfb49bea3a7ec8588e0c7a4ab</hash>
                <hash type="SHA-256">492df0663a4ca21f22c7d9bb613b43d914a78352a4f77e548846f39b6e823c3</hash>
            </hashes>
        </app>
    </reference>
    <reference type="to">
        <statement>
            <statementfull>$r2 = virtualinvoke $r1.&lt;android.content.Intent: java.lang.String getStringExtra(java.lang.String)&gt;("Secret")</statementfull>
            <statementgeneric>android.content.Intent: java.lang.String getStringExtra(java.lang.String)</statementgeneric>
            <parameters>
                <parameter>
                    <type>java.lang.String</type>
                    <value>"Secret"</value>
                </parameter>
            </parameters>
        </statement>
        <method>&lt;de.foellix.sinkapp.SinkMainActivity: void sink()&gt;</method>
        <classname>de.foellix.sinkapp.SinkMainActivity</classname>
        <app>
            <file>C:/SMSApp.apk</file>
            <hashes>
                <hash type="MD5">505197d8859303afc60ffee8ff298f39</hash>
                <hash type="SHA-1">9c2ef3ad3b0376f6c023bfca15f402f0eb00c976</hash>
                <hash type="SHA-256">8a90c056a029f2d032705be20216e8888b735131304a128752e516ac21d87a03</hash>
            </hashes>
        </app>
    </reference>
</flow>
```

I am new to using the `xml.etree.ElementTree` in Python. Could anyone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you want to select `flow` elements whose "from" hash is different to their "to" hash?

You could use retrieve these `flow` elements using the `ElementTree`'s `findall` method, with the following XPath expression

```xml
//flow[
   reference[@type='from']/app/hashes/hash[@type='SHA-256'] != 
   reference[@type='to']/app/hashes/hash[@type='SHA-256']
]
```

Comment: By the way, if you do accept this answer, please also edit your question to add the `xpath` tag to it. Thanks!